# Kentico article aspx template

Tags: c#, asp.net, content-management-system, kentico

I have to move one site from Ektron CMS to Kentico. 
I'm trying to move templates for articles now. 
I think I missed some obvious detail when I'd been reading documentation. 
There is a part of code in Ektron aspx template:

```
<%= PressReleaseContentData.Html%>
```

I think this code is in charge of showing the content of the page. How I can do the same thing in Kentico?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be my description is not correct, but I've found the answer for me. I'm getting it from TreeNode with this code:

```
<%= CMS.DocumentEngine.DocumentContext.CurrentDocument.GetValue("ArticleText") %>
```

ArticleText is a name of column with content.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what `<%= PressReleaseContentData.Html%>`
 does in Ectron, but you should check [transformation methods in Kentico](https://docs.kentico.com/k8/developing-websites/loading-and-displaying-data-on-websites/writing-transformations/reference-transformation-methods). You are probably looking for 
some `Eval` or `EditableItems` methods.